# txt: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

i have this code:

```
file_lamma = open("/users/costanzanaldi/scrivania/filelamma.txt",'r')
    for linea in file_lamma.readlines():
        linea = linea.strip().split(' ')
```

The Output is:

```
runfile('/Users/costanzanaldi/Dropbox/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python/NUOVO/pannellopiano2.py', wdir='/Users/costanzanaldi/Dropbox/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python/NUOVO')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-5-c4acfa74cc68>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/Users/costanzanaldi/Dropbox/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python/NUOVO/pannellopiano2.py', wdir='/Users/costanzanaldi/Dropbox/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python/NUOVO')

File "/Users/costanzanaldi/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Users/costanzanaldi/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/costanzanaldi/Dropbox/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python/NUOVO/pannellopiano2.py", line 59, in <module>
file_lamma = open("/users/costanzanaldi/scrivania/filelamma.txt",'r')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/users/costanzanaldi/scrivania/filelamma.txt'
```

The file's name and the path are correct... I don't know what to do

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you should double check the path you provided. 
You can access the file's parent folder using terminal, and the use command `pwd` to get the real path. Then compare it with the one in your code.
And I noticed you use "/users/". Is that correct? On my Mac OSX, it is /Users/. The path is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Linux or other Unix system you have the letter-case wrong in your open(); it should be Users not users. File and directory names are case-significant in Unix.